# How to change set different color of border radius in 4 parts using css

Tags: css, border

How to change the color of border radius.

```css
div {
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px red solid
}
```

```html
Hello
<div>
</div>
```

I want that 25% of border color should be red, then next 25% should be blue, then next 25% should be green and last pink.

How can I do this?

Comment: border-top .. border-bottom ... left, right .etc ... a small effort reading the doc will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting this?

```css
div {
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  border-left: 1px solid pink;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use gradient for your purpose. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rakowu/eokwm7uc/) In case that you wand seperate one line in several colors.

```
gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
```

```css
.border-test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
  -o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-test"></div>
```

If you just want to colorize each edge, than use the answers shown above.

If you need a hard edge, i recomend use a gradient generator.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/